# Second Monad Law:Unit

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I am reading [James Iry's blog post](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2007/10/monads-are-elephants-part-3.html) on Monads in scala. I am in part three and I am confused about his description of the second law of monads regarding Unit. Specifically this claim:

```
 unit(x) flatMap f = f(x)
```

When I apply my mental examples which are jame's previous examples of monadic types this never seems to work out

```
 val x = 1
 val f = (_:Int) * 2
 f(x) == 2 //true
 List(x) flatMap f == 2 //fail
 Some(x) flatMap f == 2 //fail
```

As a matter of fact they don't even compile due to type issues.

To clarify I understand why these are failing. I understand the how to fix them so they compile.

My confusion is that these seem to be in conflict with the theory presented in the article. Is there a step I am missing? Are these types not really monads? Is the section entitled "Second Law of Monads:Unit" incorrect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala's `flatMap` needs a function that returns a collection, not a function that returns a single element, like your function `f`.

Either use `map`:

```
List(x) map f
```

or make your function return a collection:

```
val f = (x: Int) => List(x * 2)

List(x) flatMap f
```

Note that it will also return a collection, not a single integer (you'll get `List(2)`, not just `2`).

Comment: thanks for you're reply. I understand what you are saying but my question is more related to the fact that these statements seem to conflict with the monadic laws related to the unit function.

Comment: you are correct I missed a critical part of the article where he defines the signature of the flatMap/bind method as `flatMap(f: A => M[B])`. So the issue is actually that my function was not defined correctly.

Answer (score 8):

The fact that it doesn't compile due to type issues should tell you something: `f` is not the kind of function that the monad law applies to!

`flatMap`, when seen as a monadic operation rather than a collection operation, takes a "monadic value" and a function from ordinary values to monadic values. Your `f` function is a function from ordinary values to ordinary values.

Passing `f` to `flatMap` doesn't break the monadic laws, it just doesn't mean anything at all. It's an invalid expression. Similarly `1 + "fork" - 1` doesn't violate the law from arithmetic that `1 + x - 1 = x`; from this law we might conclude that `1 + "fork" - 1` should equal "fork", when in fact it's a compiler error. That would be a silly conclusion though; the laws are only talking about things that are type-correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I just noticed that. See my comment in Jesper's post.